# How to make Chevron shape animation in HTML/CSS like on Apple iMacs page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been looking at [this](https://www.apple.com/imac-24/) page's source code with Chrome DevTools. I was viewing the page for an iPhone SE and found a down-pointing chevron icon. I clicked on the Chevron icon and saw a beautiful CSS `cubic-bezier` animation that made a megamenu appear.

**Here is the GIF link of my experience:**

[Apple iMac page video of inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyWni.gif)

Here is the HTML/CSS code I found (I did not find JavaScript code just yet):

**HTML** code:

```
<div class="ac-ln-action ac-ln-action-menucta">
     <label for="ac-ln-menustate" class="ac-ln-menucta">
          <span class="ac-ln-menucta-chevron"></span>
     </label>
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1), transform-origin 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before,
#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    width: 11px;
    height: 1px;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1), transform-origin 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
}

#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before {
    right: 50%;
    border-radius: 0.5px 0 0 0.5px;
}

#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after {
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 0 0.5px 0.5px 0;
}

#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before,
#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after {
    background: #000;
}

#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before {
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform: rotate(40deg) scaleY(1.1);
}

#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after {
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    transform: rotate(-40deg) scaleY(1.1);
}

#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

#ac-ln-menustate:checked ~ #ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron,
#ac-ln-menustate:target ~ #ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron {
    transform: translateY(-8px);
}

#ac-ln-menustate:checked ~ #ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before,
#ac-ln-menustate:target ~ #ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before {
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    transform: rotate(-40deg) scaleY(1.1);
}

#ac-ln-menustate:checked ~ #ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after,
#ac-ln-menustate:target ~ #ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after {
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform: rotate(40deg) scaleY(1.1);
}

.ac-theme-dark #ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before,
.ac-theme-dark #ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after,
#ac-localnav.ac-localnav-dark .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before,
#ac-localnav.ac-localnav-dark .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after {
    background: #fff;
}

.ac-theme-dark #ac-localnav.ac-ln-sticking .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before,
.ac-theme-dark #ac-localnav.ac-ln-sticking .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after,
.ac-localnav-dark#ac-localnav.ac-ln-sticking .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before,
.ac-localnav-dark#ac-localnav.ac-ln-sticking .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after {
    background: #fff;
}

.ac-theme-dark #ac-ln-menustate:checked ~ #ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before,
.ac-theme-dark #ac-ln-menustate:checked ~ #ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after,
.ac-theme-dark #ac-ln-menustate:target ~ #ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before,
.ac-theme-dark #ac-ln-menustate:target ~ #ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after,
#ac-ln-menustate:checked ~ .ac-localnav-dark#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before,
#ac-ln-menustate:checked ~ .ac-localnav-dark#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after,
#ac-ln-menustate:target ~ .ac-localnav-dark#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before,
#ac-ln-menustate:target ~ .ac-localnav-dark#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after {
    background: #fff;
}

#ac-localnav.ac-localnav-hero .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before,
#ac-localnav.ac-localnav-hero .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after {
    background: #fff;
}

.ac-localnav-hero#ac-localnav.ac-ln-sticking .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before,
.ac-localnav-hero#ac-localnav.ac-ln-sticking .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after {
    background: #000;
}

.ac-theme-dark .ac-localnav-hero#ac-localnav.ac-ln-sticking .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before,
.ac-theme-dark .ac-localnav-hero#ac-localnav.ac-ln-sticking .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after,
.ac-localnav-hero.ac-ln-sticking#ac-localnav.ac-localnav-dark .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before,
.ac-localnav-hero.ac-ln-sticking#ac-localnav.ac-localnav-dark .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after {
    background: #fff;
}

#ac-ln-menustate:checked ~ .ac-localnav-hero#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before,
#ac-ln-menustate:checked ~ .ac-localnav-hero#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after,
#ac-ln-menustate:target ~ .ac-localnav-hero#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before,
#ac-ln-menustate:target ~ .ac-localnav-hero#ac-localnav .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after {
    background: #000;
}
```

Does anyone know how to recreate this with more simplicity?

Comment: they use :before and :after with rotated borders to achieve that effect, I don't think there's any JS involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect is a clever manipulation of the "border" style on the span's before and after pseudo elements.

There is no javascript involved: the open / closed state depends on the `:checked` property of some parent element.

I didn't reproduce the same structure in this example, I simply wrapped the span inside an anchor, so I handled the open / close event using jQuery.

```js
jQuery('a').click( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  jQuery('.ac-ln-menucta-chevron').toggleClass('open')
})
```

```css
a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 11px;
  height: 22px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before, .ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
    width: 11px;
    height: 1px;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1),transform-origin 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
    background: #000;
}

.ac-ln-menucta-chevron::before {
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform: rotate(40deg) scaleY(1.1);
    right: 50%;
    border-radius: 0.5px 0 0 0.5px;
}


.ac-ln-menucta-chevron::after {
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    transform: rotate(-40deg) scaleY(1.1);
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 0 0.5px 0.5px 0;
}


.ac-ln-menucta-chevron.open::before  {
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    transform: rotate(-40deg) scaleY(1.1);
}

.ac-ln-menucta-chevron.open::after {
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform: rotate(40deg) scaleY(1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">
  <span class="ac-ln-menucta-chevron"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: 200 apologies for the miscommunication. I now realize that CSS can make complex things happen in more ways than JavaScript, like the CSS code I just posted!

Comment: ❤️ To you, @GrafiCode!

Comment: For javascript, here it is: 
`let anchor = document.querySelector('a');
let chevron = document.querySelector('.ac-ln-menucta-chevron');

anchor.addEventListener('click', () => {
  chevron.classList.toggle('open')
})`